# Matlab swap

Tags: matlab, matrix, swap

I am trying to create a function that will swap a specific number in a matrix with a specific number in the same matrix. For examlpe, if I start with A = [1 2 3;1 3 2], I want to be able to create B = [2 1 3; 2 3 1], simply by telling matlab to swap the 1's with the 2's. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe Matlab is a better tag for this post.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the following matrix:

```
A = [1 2 3; 1 3 2];
```

and you want all the ones to become twos and the twos to become ones, the following would be the simplest way to do it:

```
B = A;
B(find(A == 1)) = 2;
B(find(A == 2)) = 1;
```

EDIT:

As Kenny suggested, this can even be further simplified as:

```
B = A;
B(A == 1) = 2;
B(A == 2) = 1;
```

Comment: Ditto. find() is only necessary when you wish to obtain the index values. If you're just doing filtering tasks like this, it's clearer & shorter to skip it.

Comment: Agreed. I updated the answer. I had actually first done it the way Doug had (storing the index first so that I could just modify A), but then realized that the OP wanted to make a new matrix anyway. When I simplified it I forgot to remove the finds.

Comment: To clarify, when I store indices like Doug did in his example, I have fallen into the habit of using FIND. Lately, I've been dealing with very large matrices for which the logical indices would be very sparse. In such a case, storing linear indices takes up less memory than a full logical array.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to deal with the original problem is to create a **permutation vector** indicating to which numbers should the original entries be mapped to. For the example, entries [1 2 3] should be mapped respectively to [2 1 3], so that we can write

```
A = [1 2 3; 1 3 2];
perm = [2 1 3];
B = perm(A)
```

(advantage here is that everything is done in one step, and that it also works for operations more complicated than swaps ; drawback is that all elements of A must be positive integers with a known maximum)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you would to perform that particular swap (row/column interchanges are more common). Matlab often denotes ':' to represent all of something. Here's how to swap rows and columns:

To swap rows:

```
A = A([New order of rows,,...], :)
```

To Swap columns:

```
A = A(:, [New order of columns,,...])
```

To change the entire i-th column:

```
A(:, i) = [New; values; for; i-th; column]
```

For example, to swap the 2nd and 3rd columns of A = [1 2 3;1 3 2]

```
A = A(:, [1, 3, 2])
```

Comment: +1 because it seems like a very strange thing to have to do... there may be a way to get around it entirely.

Answer (score 2):

```
A = [1 2 3; 1 3 2]

alpha = 1;
beta = 2;

indAlpha = (A == alpha);
indBeta  = (A == beta);

A(indAlpha) = beta;
A(indBeta ) = alpha
```

I like this solution, it makes it clearer what is going on.  Less magic numbers, could easily be made into a function.  Recycles the same matrix if that is important.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a copy of MatLab installed, but I think you can do some thing like this;

```
for i=1:length(A)
   if (A(i)=1), B(i) = 2, B(i)=A(i) 
end
```

Note, that's only convert 1's to 2's and it looks like you also want to convert 2's to 1's, so you'll need to do a little more work.

There also probably a much more elegant way of doing it given you can do this sort of thing in Matlab

```
>> A = 1:1:3
A = [1,2,3]
>> B = A * 2
B = [2,4,6]
```

There might be a swapif primitive you can use, but I haven't used Matlab in a long time, so I'm not sure the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In reference to [tarn's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647042/matlab-swap/647125#647125) more elegant way of swapping values you could use a *permutation* matrix as follows:

```
>> a =[1 2 3];
>> T = [1 0 0;
        0 0 1;
        0 1 0];
>> b = a*T
ans =
    1 3 2
```

but this will swap column 2 and column 3 of the vector (matrix) *a*; whereas the question asked about swapping the 1's and 2's.

**Update**

To swap elements of two different values look into the find function

> > ind = find(a==1);

returns the  indices of all the elements with value, 1.  Then you can use [Mitch's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647042/matlab-swap/647143#647143) suggestion to change the value of the elements using index arrays.  Remeber that find returns the linear index into the matrix; the first element has index 1 and the last element of an *nxm* matrix has linear index *n*m*. The linear index is counted down the columns.  For example

```
>> b = [1 3 5;2 4 6];
>> b(3) % same as b(1,2)
ans = 3
>> b(5) % same as b(1,3)
ans = 5
>> b(6) % same as b(2,3)
ans = 6
```

Comment: Hello everyone, I just finished up writing the code. I wanna thank you all for your help.